# Creation of GUI in a correct window

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to create a GUI with 4 fields.

1. url
2. username
3. password
4. statement

At the very first time, the fields should be empty. Later, all the fields beside the password field should contain the info from the last time.

Problems:

1. The GUI window should not have a standard size

   What I would like to achieve:

   - When the window opens, it should dynamically adjust to the screen size of a laptop, e.g. center, 20% of the screen
2. The fourth field (statement) can be very long and the GUI window automatically becomes too long.

   What I would like to achieve:

   - For the fourth field, the String should be broken down to multiple lines. After breaking the field down to three lines instead of continuing to breaking it to a fourth, an option could be a scroll bar.

Until now I have found some Objects that could help.

- *JOptionPane*
- *JPanel*
- *JTextArea* for the fourth long field

  For the *JTextArea*, there is also the

  - *JScrollPane*
  - *.setLineWrap(true)* to break lines
  - *.setWrapStyleWord(true)* to break lines after a word

Example of my code:

```
JPanel pane = new JPanel();
// adding GridLayout
pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2));
// fields are filled just as an example
// later they will get substituted by variables
JTextField url = new JTextField ("https:testin.com");
JTextField username = new JTextField ("theDude");
JTextArea statement = new JTextArea("This statement can becomme very very very long :)");
statement.setLineWrap(true);
statement.setWrapStyleWord(true);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(statement);
pane.add(scrollPane);
// add infos to pane
pane.add(new JLabel ("Enter url: "));
pane.add(url);
pane.add(new JLabel ("Enter username: "));
pane.add(username);
pane.add(new JLabel ("Enter password: "));
pane.add(new JPasswordField());
pane.add(new JLabel ("Enter statement: "));
pane.add(statement);
//write it to a OK_CANCEL JOptionPane
int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,pane, "Fill all the fields",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

[image]

Comment: “20% of the screen” —It is not a GUI developer’s place to force sizes that way.  Swing and the desktop and the user’s preferences determine font sizes, and Swing components automatically fit the size of their respective fonts.  JOptionPane will center the window for you.  As for arranging your components, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/.  Usually the label/field UI pattern is accomplished with a [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html).

Comment: Besides `GridBag`, note that Oracle actually recommends using a GUI layout tool, like NetBeans.  Check their [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and read the special note near the beginning where it recommends a GUI layout tool and links to a NetBeans page.

Comment: @markspace what if I am using the intellij IDE?

Comment: I don't know that IDE so you'll have to ask on their forums, I guess.  No reason you can't use both NetBeans and IntelliJ on the same projects.  NetBeans just makes regular code for its GUI classes.

Comment: @VGR Thanks for the tip. It kind off works with the GridBagLayout, although I have to set beforehand a size for the field input. Is there a way to fetch through the input from the fields and break down a long given input to more lines?

Comment: *"I have to set beforehand a size for the field input."* No you don't. The size of a text field should be determined by the number of columns and the font size, so `JTextField username = new JTextField ("theDude");` should be more like `JTextField username = new JTextField ("theDude", c);` where `c` is the number of columns.

Comment: "what if I am using the intellij IDE" you can use any IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the height (number of visible lines) of `JTextArea` using `setRows()`. Try below example. I started from your code and did few changes.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ThreeLinesTextArea
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    // Change to GridBagLayout
    pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    JTextField url = new JTextField("https:testin.com");
    JTextField username = new JTextField("theDude");

    JTextArea statement = new JTextArea("This statement can becomme very very very long :)");
    statement.setLineWrap(true);
    statement.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    // Use setRows() to make text area have multiple lines
    statement.setRows(3);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(statement);

    //This line is removed. scrollPane is added at the end.
    //pane.add(scrollPane);

    pane.add(new JLabel("Enter url: "),
        new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST,
            GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2), 0, 0));
    pane.add(url,
        new GridBagConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST,
            GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2), 0, 0));
    pane.add(new JLabel("Enter username: "),
        new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST,
            GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2), 0, 0));
    pane.add(username,
        new GridBagConstraints(1, 1, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST,
            GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2), 0, 0));
    pane.add(new JLabel("Enter password: "),
        new GridBagConstraints(0, 2, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST,
            GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2), 0, 0));
    pane.add(new JPasswordField(15),
        new GridBagConstraints(1, 2, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST,
            GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2), 0, 0));
    pane.add(new JLabel("Enter statement: "),
        new GridBagConstraints(0, 3, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST,
            GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2), 0, 0));
    pane.add(scrollPane,
        new GridBagConstraints(1, 3, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.WEST,
            GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2), 0, 0));

    int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, pane, "Fill all the fields",
        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Brilliant :) Two questions though. I thought that with "ipadx" I could select the width size of the white fields. This somehow did not work. In which part, did you select the size for all four white fields? The second question. How is it possible to get the values that the user writes in the white fields?

Comment: After some digging and testing, I found out that "GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL" does somehow the trick. It just adjusts the whole window to the width of the parameter (horizontally).

Comment: @Georgios, yes, when we set `GridBagConstraints.fill` to `GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL`, the component "fills" the cell. To get values from text components you can use `getText()` method.